# Strip file name of non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, command-line, wildcard

How can I rename a file to a file name stripped of all other characters except letters and numbers?

For example:

**It's_A Brand (New) #Year,,2016!.txt** renamed to **ItsABrandNewYear2016.txt**

Is it possible to do this with Windows batch?

Comment: FWIW, here's a pretty solid regex for matching non-alphanumeric characters up until the file's extension: [`/[^A-Z0-9](?=.*?\.[a-z]+$)/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/pA5aT7/1)

Comment: Yes it's possible, you can find/google many examples of stripping or replacing the characters using batch files. If you don't want to be bothered with the research then why not simply use a utility like Advanced Renamer?

Comment: You neither want to match a word character (\w) nor a period (.). All other characters should be replaced with "". This comes down to `([^\w\.])` with a global matching. All captured groups need to be replaced. I am on a Mac so no idea how to do it with MS but the regex can get you started.

Comment: @Jan not a good expression at all. A period may be part of the file name and not just separating the extension. Also, `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so this will let an underscore get by. Finally, as a side note, you don't need to escape a period in a character class.

Comment: @Sam Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the code below as a Batch file (with .BAT extension):

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "oldname=It's_A Brand (New) #Year,,2016!.txt"
for %%f in ("%oldname%") do (
   for /F %%a in ('cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "%%~Nf"') do ECHO ren "%%~f" "%%a%%~Xf"
)
goto :EOF


@end

// JScript section

WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(WScript.Arguments(0).replace(/[\W_]/g,""));
```

Output:

```
ren "It's_A Brand (New) #Year,,2016!.txt" "ItsABrandNewYear2016.txt"
```

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "filename=It's_A Br@$^[-+={;}]a.nd & (New) #Year,,2016!.txt"
SET "newname="
FOR %%a IN ("%filename%") DO CALL :strip "%%~na" "%%~xa"
ECHO RENAME "%filename%" to "%newname%"

GOTO :EOF

:strip
SET "string=%~1"
IF NOT DEFINED string SET "newname=%newname:~0,-1%"&GOTO :EOF
:striploop
SET "char=%string:~0,1%"
ECHO "%char%"|FINDSTR /i /r "[a-z] [0-9]" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "newname=%newname%%char%"
SET "string=%string:~1%"
IF DEFINED string GOTO striploop
SHIFT
SET "newname=%newname%."
GOTO strip
```

Reasonably straight-forward. Note that only the last dot in the name (if any) is preserved.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a hybrid batch/JScript utility called [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) that provides regular expression renaming directly from the command line, without any additional scripting required. It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

The solution is similar to Aacini's, except the find/replace is applied to the entire name, so the regular expression must be a bit more complex to preserve the extension dot.

```
jren "[^a-z0-9.]|\.(?!txt$)" "" /i /fm "It's_A Brand (New) #Year,,2016!.txt"
```

The solution can easily be made to remove all non-alphanumeric characters from all file names in the current directory, except it preserves the extension dots.

```
jren "[^a-z0-9.]|\.(?![^.]+$)" "" /i
```

Note that JREN is a batch script, so you must use `call jren` if you use the command within another batch script.